# WCF - Service host closing down after error

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

We have a WCF service published in IIS on our local development machine.  The service exposes several methods, one of them accepting an array of bytes as a parameter. When invoked we are getting an error when sending over 3MBs of data.

When invoked for the first time we get the following error:  “An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - WCF.”

If we invoke it again we then get this error: “An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://[server]/service/method.  This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.”

We know how to solve the error by increasing the buffersize and maxreceivedmessagesize in the binding and the maxrequestlength in the system.httpruntime.
The problem we find is that the error is causing the service host to close down and stops accepting further requests.

We’d like to know why the error is causing the servicehost to close down. 
I was under the impression that any exceptions caused by a request would return a faultexception but wouldn’t necessarily close the host. Any even if the host is closed on the next request it would open it again.

Could somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the maxRequestEntityAllowed limit.

See:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/limits
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx